# Is there a way to enforce similarity between two words in python?

Tags: python, word2vec, corpus

I have tried using word2vec but I want to change the similarity between two words. Preferably, not one by one manually. Another option I was considering was creating a corpus that would enforce the correct similarity but I don't know how to do this. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Word2Vec uses large amounts of real-world usage data to create word-vectors that are useful for certain things **because** they accurately reflect the relationships in the training text.

Changing any vectors' position is, in one sense, trivial: just modify the array to whatever values you want, Make all their dimensions zeros! All `100.0`! Whatever!

For example, if you want the words `'apple'` and `'orange'` to have identical vectors, and thus ~`1.0` similarity, it's easy to change one to the other. Assuming you've used the popular Python Gensim library to train a `Word2Vec` model into `my_w2v_model`:

```
my_wv = my_w2v_model.wv
print(my_wv.similarity('apple', 'orange'))
my_wv['apple'] = my_wv['orange']
print(my_wv.similarity('apple', 'orange'))
```

But, now the model has lost any idea of the apple/orange distinction, and the `'apple'` vector will now have no neighbors or value other than as an exact synonym of `'orange'`.

So, since such changes can destroy the reason for using word-vectors in the 1st place, it's important to know what kind of change, & for what hoped-for benefits, you're seeking.

Maybe you want to clobber end-values directly, or nudge words a little bit, or something else. In particular, if you mostly want words to retain their relationships with *other* words, you'll want to make more subtle changes.

In some cases, it might make the most sense to **change or extend the training data**, to shift the model training towards the similarities you want. As one rough quickie example, you could consider preprocessing the data to take every text where `'apple'` appears, and with 50% probability , replace `'apple'` with `'orange'` (and vice-versa for `'orange'`). That'd tend to confuse the two in the training texts, and thus result in highly-similar end-vectors, which each still (by the influence of the *unchanged* texts) is also much like the original word/word-neighbors.

(With more details of your aims, more specific suggestions might be possible.)